# Ubuntu GDB to be set to intel

Tags: c, gdb

I want GDB to be set to intel. I want to configure this setting to run every time GDB starts up. can you please give instructions of how to do this with an explanation if possible, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the file `~/.gdbinit` add `set disassembly-flavor intel`